# Google script vertical panel cutting off entries

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a small gui in a google script to display the user some data. 
The vertical panel that I am using cuts off some of the data that needs to be viewed.  How can I fix this besides just using setSize(heigh, width)?

Ideally, I would like just a horizontal and vertical scroll bar. Possible?

Thanks, here is my code so far.

```
function viewTestsHandler(e)
{
  var row;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var ui = UiApp.createApplication();

  //create a ui for user
  var permitList = [];
  var view = ui.createVerticalPanel();
  var header = ui.createHorizontalPanel();
  var fNameLabel = ui.createTextBox().setValue('First Name');
  var lNameLabel = ui.createTextBox().setValue('Last Name');
  var dateLabel = ui.createTextBox().setValue('Final Date to Make Up');
  var timeLimitLabel = ui.createTextBox().setValue('Time Limit');
  header.add(fNameLabel);
  header.add(lNameLabel);
  header.add(dateLabel);
  header.add(timeLimitLabel);
  view.add(header);

  //scroll through and collect each permit for the user, and place it into a horizontal   row
  var numPermits = 0;
  for(var i = 2; i <= sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow(); i++)
  {
    Logger.log('i = ' + i + 'email: ' + email + ' row user name: ' + sheet.getRange(i,          getColumnByName('Username')).getValue());
if(email == sheet.getRange(i, getColumnByName('Username')).getValue())
{
  Logger.log('Adding row ' + i + 'to view list');
  var tempRow = ui.createHorizontalPanel();
  numPermits++;

  //Pertinent fields: First name, last name, final date, time limit, special instructions
  var fName = ui.createTextBox().setValue(sheet.getRange(i, getColumnByName('Student First Name')).getValue()).setReadOnly(true);
  var lName = ui.createTextBox().setValue(sheet.getRange(i, getColumnByName('Student Last Name')).getValue()).setReadOnly(true);
  var finalDate = ui.createDateBox().setValue(sheet.getRange(i, getColumnByName('Final Date to Make Up Exam')).getValue());
  var timeLimit = ui.createTextBox().setValue(sheet.getRange(i, getColumnByName('Time Limit (minutes)')).getValue());
  tempRow.add(fName);
  tempRow.add(lName);
  tempRow.add(finalDate);
  tempRow.add(timeLimit);
  //add the row to the view
  view.add(tempRow);
   }
}

  if (numPermits > 0)
  {
    ui.add(view);
    ss.show(ui);
  }
}
```

EDIT: I think I have narrowed down the problem: I am able to scroll around the GUI using my mouse, but the scroll wheel is not visible on the screen.  As in, perhaps the border of one of the panels is too thick?  Not sure if that makes sense, but I hope this piece of extra information helps someone answer this!

Thanks,

Jordan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [UiApp ScrollPanel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/scroll-panel) like this in your code:

```
ui.add(ui.createScrollPanel(view));
```

---

edit : example code in a SS

```
function testScrol() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test as a form');
  var master = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttributes({'padding':'15px'});
  for(var n=0;n<20;n++){
    master.add(app.createTextBox().setName('textBox'+n).setId('textBox'+n));
  }
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('getData').addCallbackElement(master);
  var btn = app.createButton('submit',handler);
  master.add(btn);
  app.add(app.createScrollPanel(master).setHeight(300));
  ss.show(app);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it did not quite work.  I added the code in lieu of the line 'ui.add(view);', but I can not see the scroll bar.  I am able to use my mouse middle button to scroll around the ui, so there is clearly a scrolling capability active, but I just can't see the scroll bars.  Why would this happen?

Comment: maybe you could try setting the height of the vertical panel (view) to something higher than the Ui (.setHeight()) just to test if the scrollbar appears. It worked in my test.

Comment: here is the test I made in a webapp : https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyu-4p_9mhgtLzMTZLvuf3gVUpIMwuRSjjK10aivMrJ3ISW9gU/exec

Comment: Creating a scrollPanel allows it to scroll properly, but I would like the user to see a scroll wheel.  I am dealing with users who are, shall we say, resistant, to technology and change, so I want it to look as nice as possible =P.  Thanks again though, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I'll edit with another example in a SS, I've added a setHeigth too.

Comment: Ok thanks for the code, I will try to adapt mine similarly, and figure out what the problem was.  Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: you're welcome. pls think about accepting when it works ;) (and I'm pretty sure it will) Don't forget to fix a height limit for your view vertical panel.

Comment: I was able to adapt it to my needs, thank you so much for your help!